# Something turned something meaning

Tags: meaning

the pop star Turned politician meaning. The whole sentence is like this:

> *The pop star turned politician was arrested.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you changed, normally and in this case that you changed career. It's often used with hyphens to indicate that it's spoken a bit faster than the words would be separately. Example:

> she also favors Peggy, the secretary-turned-copywriter and Draper's protege

Comment: Hyphens in this context indicate that the phrase should be understood as a unit. Any pronunciation change is a consequence of that.